# OneDrive/SharePoint error 429

Tags: sharepoint, office365, onedrive, http-status-code-429

I use OneDrive/OneDrive for Business REST API to access files on Office365 (MS-hosted) server. Quite often error 429 is returned although I'm definitely not doing thousands of requests. Exponential back-off even up to 60 seconds doesn't always lead to recovery. I've read article from MS about throttling and how to avoid it and have implemented "request decorations", but still getting this error too often.

429 response looks like this:

HTTP/1.1 429
(...)
{"error":{"code":"activityLimitReached","innererror":{"code":"throttledRequest"},"message":"The request has been throttled"}}

Comment: It seems like OneDrive for Business REST API is basically useless :( We are getting 429 for very simple and light operations.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue where even the transfer of a single small text file was severely throttled during business hours. At times every request was returned with a 429 message even though the indicated backoff times were implemented. Microsoft Support have provided the following information:

1. All non-interactive applications will experience throttling during
   business hours. This has been the case since February 2018.
2. There is currently no way to stop the throttling.
3. A small reduction in throttling can be achieved if the app is a registered 
   app store application.
4. Non-interactive applications should be scheduled to run from 6pm to 6am 
   local time on weekdays and all day on weekends during which time the extra 
   throttling for non-interactive applications is removed.

Comment: This answer is accurate, bit if you want it from an "official" source you can listen to this [Ignite 2018 presentation](https://myignite.techcommunity.microsoft.com/sessions/65661)